# Flink 1.16 task managers are not processing data after restart, Explicit Exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-flink

I have a used below code for retry approach in flink . But , Job is getting restarted because of checkpoint . But the failure task is not reprocessing the data. Can you please help me out from this situation.

```
 StreamExecutionEnvironment streamExecutionEnvironment = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        streamExecutionEnvironment.setParallelism(1);
        // start a checkpoint every 1000 ms
        streamExecutionEnvironment.enableCheckpointing(5000);
        // streamExecutionEnvironment.setParallelism(2);

        // advanced options:

        // set mode to exactly-once (this is the default)
        streamExecutionEnvironment.getCheckpointConfig().setCheckpointingMode(CheckpointingMode.EXACTLY_ONCE);
        streamExecutionEnvironment.setStateBackend(new HashMapStateBackend());
        //streamExecutionEnvironment.setStateBackend(new FsStateBackend("hdfs://namenode:40010/flink/checkpoints"));
        // checkpoints have to complete within one minute, or are discarded
        streamExecutionEnvironment.getCheckpointConfig().setCheckpointTimeout(600000);

        // allow only one checkpoint to be in progress at the same time
        streamExecutionEnvironment.getCheckpointConfig().setMaxConcurrentCheckpoints(1);

       // streamExecutionEnvironment.getCheckpointConfig().setCheckpointStorage("file:///opt/flink/checkpoint-dir/");
        streamExecutionEnvironment.setRestartStrategy(RestartStrategies.fixedDelayRestart(
                4, // number of restart attempts
                Time.of(4, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // delay
        ));

    DataStreamSource<String> rawDataStream = sourceFactory.readSignalStream(streamExecutionEnvironment);
            SingleOutputStreamOperator<String> rawSignalStream =
                    rawDataStream.filter(string -> Objects.nonNull(string) && StringUtils.isNotEmpty(string));
```

This above line we are reading the stream from the source . So Flink has created 3 task and each one doing the data processing as per my business logic.
So the rawsignalstream is failing because of the exceptions. So Checkpoint is recreating the task as expected.
But during the exception it was processing the payload1 , So I am expecting , after the restart it should reprocess the payload1 .but its not happening.

Comment: Please provide more information. What exactly do you expect to happen, and how do you know it isn't happening?

Comment: Also, what sources are you using, and how are they configured?

Comment: I have explicitly raise a exception in the one of the task, So as per the above code , that task is restarted but processing of that task is not happening

Comment: Please go back to one of the earlier versions of this question, and share enough so that your problem can be reproduced, and the question becomes clear. As it stands, I don't understand what you are trying to do, or what the question is.

Comment: David, Yes agree , its restarting the task. But my question is ,it is not reprocessing the data. I mean , there is a signal1  is received and its failed in the task2 . So task 2 is restarting fine , after restart, it has to take the same signal1. but that is not happening

Comment: So we are losing the signal 1.

Comment: Again, you haven't shared enough to reproduce (or diagnose) the problem.

Comment: Updated the description . Can you please provide me a solution for that.